# Are 南瓜小米粥 (nánguā xiǎomǐ zhōu) and 小米南瓜粥 (xiǎomǐ nánguā zhōu) the same thing?

Tags: food

I've had both 南瓜小米粥 (nánguā xiǎomǐ zhōu; pumpkin and millet congee) and 小米南瓜粥 (xiǎomǐ nánguā zhōu; millet and pumpkin congee) in China.  They were different; the first one I've had many times and it usually (always?) has chunks of pumpkin, whereas the second one I've had once and it was more of a pumpkin puree.  I'm not sure if this is just a difference in shops where I bought it.

In fact, when I bought 小米南瓜粥, I asked for 南瓜小米粥 as that is what I'm accustomed to asking for.  The lady at the counter corrected me, calling it 小米南瓜粥.

So my question is...

**Q**: Are 南瓜小米粥 and 小米南瓜粥 the same thing?

Comment: 南瓜小米粥 Pumpkin congee
    百科

    材料： 老南瓜，小米，枸杞做法： 1.南瓜皮切薄片，小米洗净。锅里放适量清水，水开后放入南瓜小米，大火煮开。 2.转小火，慢慢熬到小米开花，南瓜煮化。 3.加入枸杞，拌匀后再煮几分钟即可。
note addition of 枸杞.......
 
小米南瓜粥 Millet and pumpkin Congee  原料： 小米100g、南瓜300g做法： 1、南瓜去皮切块，小米洗净后用清水浸泡20分钟； 2、准备半瓶开水，倒入电饭锅中，下小米煮30分钟；煮小米时，用搅拌机将南瓜打成泥； 3、30分钟后，加入南瓜同煮，继续煮15分钟左右即可，中间要时时搅一搅，避免粘锅。 适合人群 1-3岁儿童、老年人均可
本内容来源于 百度百科

Comment: note difference in preceding recipes，南瓜小米粥  老（old？meaning 成熟的 ripe？）南瓜皮切薄片 Peel and thinly slice ......小米南瓜粥：去皮切块 Peel and Cut into chunks 用搅拌机将南瓜打成泥 use blender to mash pumpkin，thus in agreement  with answer 小米南瓜粥 seems to involve a greater degree of mechanical reduction to a soft pulpy state than 南瓜小米粥,although neither recipe leaves any chunks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think they're different.

`南瓜小米粥` is `小米粥` with `南瓜`: as you said, it's millet congee with chunks of pumpkin in genaral.

[image]

`小米南瓜粥` is `南瓜粥` with `小米`; it's more like pumpkin puree, with millet grains.

[image]

Of course what the name means indeed largely depends on the restaurant.